Is there a formal definition/name of the minimum distance between discrete sets?
If I have two sets $A$ and $B$, each containing $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^m$, I can perform a linear assignment algorithm to pair each point $A_i \in A$ to a point $B_i \in B$ such that for these particular pairings $$\sum_{i=1}^n \lVert A_i - B_i \rVert_2$$ is minimal. Does this minimal distance I can define between the two sets $A$ and $B$ have a particular name? I know that the Hausdorff metric is usually the typical metric used for distances between sets, and I'm not even sure if this quantity would satisfy the conditions of being a metric, however, that's not my concern. I have done a preliminary search and any usage of this distance I've found does not reference it as any particular name. My inquiry is merely whether or not this quantity has a formal name.
EDIT: I've added a picture to give some visual understanding of what I'm doing. Here the $d_{tot}$ is the minimal distance of all possible pairings between points of the two sets.
EDIT 2: Effectively the concept at play is the application of the Wasserstein distance. The new question is how do you go from the general definition of the Wasserstein distance to just using it to find this minimal distance between sets? Additionally, can the Wasserstein distance be defined using any metric? Could one use angular distance or a supremum norm instead?


I think what people typically look at (for $q$-valued maps as is done for example in here https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0060) $$ \mathcal{G}(A,B)= \min_{\sigma\in S_m}\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^m \vert A_j -B_{\sigma(j)} \vert^2}.$$ This coincides with the $L^2$-Wasserstein distance on the space of positive measures
with finite second moment (see remark $0.3$ in the previously linked paper for references).

@SeverinSchraven This does appear to be getting at what I'm talking about. If you could write an answer with more detail and explanation of terms, I'd gladly accept it

David, it does not quite correspond to what you wrote (due to the missing square). There would also be a lot to say about the Wasserstein metric. What would you be interested in?

@SeverinSchraven Is the term $|A_j - B_{\sigma(j)}|^2$ the Euclidean norm between $A_j$ and $B_{\sigma(j)}$?

Yes, it is... I am not entirely sure what I was thinking about. The two expression are indeed the same (up to the square root I have picked, but that does not matter too much). In any case, what would you like to know about the Wasserstein metric?

@SeverinSchraven Specifically how it has been solved and used to find these distances as described. At a cursory glance, it seems like the Wasserstein metric is more general than what I'm using it for. Could provide how the general definition leads to this kind of distance for discrete Euclidean sets of equal size?

@SeverinSchraven Additionally, can it be defined around any common metric between two points, e.g. cosine-similarity of angles?

It is indeed much more general. I think the key is to associate to $A$ the measure $\sum_{j=1}^n \delta_{A_j}$ and then let the Wasserstein metric do its thing. Unfortunately, I am a bit rusty on my optimal transport, thus, it might take a while until I'll write an answer. However, if you include what you wrote above in your post, then there might be a another person (presumably much more capable than me) who could write an answer.
